# Divide columns into groups (rows) based on their cumulative width with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of columns (of varying widths) being generated and I need to divide them into groups or rows based on their widths. Every time the cumulative width of the columns reaches 100% I'd like to group those columns in a new div.

I asked a friend to look into this for me and he came back with this, but I still can't get it working. If anyone can offer any help it would be much appreciated.

```
$.fn.gridRows = function() {
    var cumulativeWidth = 0;
    var items = [];
    $('.column',this).each(function(index){
        var col = $(this);
        col.data('index', index);
        var percentageWidth = (100 * parseFloat(col.css('width')) / parseFloat(col.parent().css('width')));
        cumulativeWidth += percentageWidth;
        items.push(index);
        if(cumulativeWidth >= 100){
            if(items.length == 1){
                col.wrap('<div></div>');
            }else{
                var selector = '*' + items.join('][data-index=').substring(1) +']';
                $(selector).wrap('<div></div>');
            }
            items = [];
            cumulativeWidth = 0;
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body .group').gridRows();
});
```

Comment: What's not working? What's the problem? What's your question?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be adding the div's. I can see in firebug that it's indexing the .columns, and if I add an alert to show the cumulativeWidth it reaches 100 then resets, but never adds the required divs.

Comment: Try `alert()`ing (or otherwise tracing) your selector in the else block, see if it takes the value you expect it to. Does it work when `items.length==1`?

Comment: If I alert() when items.length==1 I get nothing (although I should based on the HTML). If I alert() the else block I get cumulative widths well over 100, when, based on HTML the most anything should add up to is 100.

Comment: the HTML it's looking at is as follows:

    <div class="group">
        <hgroup class="column fullWidth"></hgroup>
        <div class="column fullWidth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <article class="column one_third"></article>
        <article class="column one_third"></article>
        <article class="column one_third"></article>
    </div>

Comment: I mean `alert(selector)`. Check if `selector` takes the value you expect it to.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'd expect it to return, not having written this, hopefully an array of .columns... but probably not `*][data-index=1][data-index=2]`which is what it's giving me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed it a bit, but this works for me. At least, it groups columns into boxes with a total width of no more than 100%!

```
$.fn.gridRows = function() {
    var cumulativeWidth = 0,
        columns = $('.column',this),
        rowItems = [];

    var group = function(items) {
        if (items.length) {
            $('<div></div>').insertBefore(items[0]).append(items);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = columns.length; i < l; ++i) {
        var $column = $(columns[i]),
            width = Math.round(100/$column.parent().width() * $column.width());

        if (cumulativeWidth + width > 100) {
            group(rowItems);
            cumulativeWidth = 0;
            rowItems = [];
        }
        cumulativeWidth += width;
        rowItems.push($column[0]);
    }

    group(rowItems);
}
```